# sort two files by header so that they are in matching field order

Tags: r, bash, perl, awk

I have two files that each have 700 fields, where 699/700 of the fields have matching headers. I would like to reorder the fields so that they are in the same order in both files (though which order is irrelevant). For example, given:

```
File1:
FRUIT MSMC1 MSMC24 MSMC2 MSMC10
Apple 1 2 3 2
Pear 2 1 4 5

File2:
VEG MSMC24 MSMC1 MSMC2 MSMC10
Onion 2 1 3 2
Radish 0 3 9 3
```

I would like both files to have the first field as the fields that are not common to both files, then the rest of the fields in the same order in both files, for example one possible outcome would be:

```
File1:
FRUIT MSMC1 MSMC2 MSMC10 MSMC24
Apple 1 3 2 2
Pear 2 4 5 1

File2:
VEG MSMC1 MSMC2 MSMC10 MSMC24
Onion 1 3 2 2
Radish 3 9 3 0
```

Comment: Are the fields separated by space or any whitespace?  Are there ever any quotes or escapes, e.g. `"Green Onion" 1 2 3 4` or `Green\ Onion 1 2 3 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table`, this can help you
First read the files,

```
 library(data.table)
 dt1 <- fread("file1.csv")
 dt2 <- fread("file2.csv")
```

then, get the names of the fields, the common ones

```
 ndt1 <- names(dt1)[-1]
 ndt2 <- names(dt2)[-1]
 common <- intersect(ndt1, ndt2)
```

and now you can just apply the new order

```
 setorder(dt1, c(ndt1[1], setdiff(ndt1, common), common))
 setorder(dt2, c(ndt2[1], setdiff(ndt2, common), common))
```

Comment: In base R, just `common <- intersect(names(dat1),names(dat2)); dat1 <- dat1[c(setdiff(names(dat1),ints),ints)]` etc would be equivalent.

Comment: and the dplyr/ggplot equivalent `library(dplyr); library(ggplot2); as_data_frame(dt1)[ndt1[1] %>% c(setdiff(ndt1, common)) %>% c(common)]`

Comment: How could these answers be modified if one file were to be a subset of the other (not all columns from file 1 are in file2)?

Comment: can you provide an example? the script does not assume there is any shared columns... or the other way around. if all columns of 1 are in 2, then you will just have `setdiff(ndt1, common)`  empty.

Comment: @theo4786 See my updated answer. Includes the `map` construct.

Answer (score 1):

A perl solution that leaves the first file as is and writes the second file with the columns arranged in the same order as the first file. It reads the 2 files supplied on the command line (which follow the script name).

**Update:** Added the `map $_ // (),` phrase to allow the second file to be a subset of the first file. Answer to his question *How could these answers be modified if one file were to be a subset of the other (not all columns from file 1 are in file2)? – theo4786*

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# commandline: perl script_name.pl fruits.csv veg.csv

my (undef, @fruit_hdrs) = split ' ', <> and close ARGV;

my @veg_hdrs;

while (<>) {
    my ($name, @cols) = split;

    # only executes for the first line (header line) of second file
    @veg_hdrs = @cols unless @veg_hdrs;

    my %line;
    @line{ @veg_hdrs } = @cols;

    print join(" ", $name, map $_ // (), @line{ @fruit_hdrs } ), "\n";
}
```

Output is:

```
VEG MSMC1 MSMC24 MSMC2 MSMC10
Onion 1 2 3 2
Radish 3 0 9 3
```

Answer (score 0):

In perl, the tool for this job is a hash slice.

You can access values of a hash as `@hash{@keys}`.

So something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @headers; 
my $type; 

my @rows; 

#iterate data - would do this with a normal 'open'
while ( <DATA> ) {
  #set headers if the leading word is all upper case 
  if ( m/^[A-Z]+\s/ ) { 
      #seperate out type (VEG/FRUIT) from the other headings. 
      chomp ( ( $type, @headers ) = split ); 
      #print for debugging
      print Dumper \@headers;
  }
  else {
     #create a hash to store this row. 
     my %this_row;
     #split the row on whitespace, capturing name and ordered fields by header row. 
     ( my $name, @this_row{@headers} ) = split; 
     #insert name and type into the hash
     $this_row{name} = $name;
     $this_row{type} = $type;
     #print for debugging
     print Dumper \%this_row;
     #store it in @rows
     push ( @rows, \%this_row ); 
  }
}

#print output:
#header line
print join ("\t", "name", "type", @headers ),"\n";
#iterate rows, extract ordered by _last_ set of headers. 
foreach my $row ( @rows ) { 
    print join ( "\t", $row->{name}, $row->{type}, @{$row}{@headers} ),"\n";
}

__DATA__
FRUIT MSMC1 MSMC24 MSMC2 MSMC10
Apple 1 2 3 2
Pear 2 1 4 5
VEG MSMC24 MSMC1 MSMC2 MSMC10
Onion 2 1 3 2
Radish 0 3 9 3
```

Note - I've used `Data::Dumper` for diagnostics - those lines can be removed, but I've left them because illustrate what's going on. 
Likewise reading from `<DATA>` - normally you'd open a file handle, or just use `while ( <> ) {` to read STDIN or files specified on command line.

The ordering of output is based on the last header line 'seen' - you can of course, sort that, or reorder it.

If you need to handle mismatching columns, this will error on the missing one. In this scenario, we can break out `map` to fill in any blanks, and use a hash for `headers` to ensure we capture them all.

E.g.;

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @headers; 
my %headers_combined; 
my $type; 

my @rows; 

#iterate data - would do this with a normal 'open'
while ( <DATA> ) {
  #set headers if the leading word is all upper case 
  if ( m/^[A-Z]+\s/ ) { 
      #seperate out type (VEG/FRUIT) from the other headings. 
      chomp ( ( $type, @headers ) = split ); 
      #add to hash of headers, to preserve uniques
      $headers_combined{$_}++ for @headers; 
      #print for debugging
      print Dumper \@headers;
  }
  else {
     #create a hash to store this row. 
     my %this_row;
     #split the row on whitespace, capturing name and ordered fields by header row. 
     ( my $name, @this_row{@headers} ) = split; 
     #insert name and type into the hash
     $this_row{name} = $name;
     $this_row{type} = $type;
     #print for debugging
     print Dumper \%this_row;
     #store it in @rows
     push ( @rows, \%this_row ); 
  }
}

#print output:
#header line
#note - extract keys from hash, not the @headers array. 
#sort is needed to order them, because default is unordered. 
print join ("\t", "name", "type", sort keys %headers_combined ),"\n";
#iterate rows, extract ordered by _last_ set of headers. 
foreach my $row ( @rows ) { 
    print join ( "\t", $row->{name}, $row->{type}, map { $row->{$_} // '' } sort keys %headers_combined ),"\n";
}

__DATA__
FRUIT MSMC1 MSMC24 MSMC2 MSMC10 OTHER
Apple 1 2 3 2 x
Pear 2 1 4 5 y 
VEG MSMC24 MSMC1 MSMC2 MSMC10 NOTHING
Onion 2 1 3 2 p
Radish 0 3 9 3 z
```

Here, `map { $row->{$_} // '' } sort keys %headers_combined` takes all the keys of the hash, returns them in order, and then extracts that key from the row - or gives an empty space if it's undefined. (thats what `//` does)

Answer (score 0):

This will reorder the fields in file2 to match the order in file1:

```
$ cat tst.awk
FNR==1 {
    fileNr++
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        name2nr[fileNr,$i] =  i
        nr2name[fileNr,i]  = $i
    }
}
fileNr==2 { 
    printf "%s", $1
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        printf "%s%s", OFS, $(name2nr[1,nr2name[2,i]])
    }
    print ""
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
VEG MSMC1 MSMC24 MSMC2 MSMC10
Onion 1 2 3 2
Radish 3 0 9 3
```

With GNU awk you can delete the `fileNr++` line and use `ARGIND` instead of `fileNr` everywhere else.